# How to convert String to variable name in Java?

Tags: java, variables

I want to covert the value of a `String` to a variable name in Java.

I've found the solution for this problem, but in javascript([Convert string to variable name in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613834/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-javascript)) not in java.

```
boolean hi;
boolean bye;
boolean question;

String myString = "hi";

public void changeBooleanValue(){

    [value of myString]= true;
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Here are two helpful posts I found: [Creating a variable name using a String value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value) & [To use a string value as a variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974558/to-use-a-string-value-as-a-variable-name)

Comment: This sounds like an [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you actually trying to do? There's probably a much better way to do it in Java than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
boolean hi;
boolean bye;

void setTrue(String name) {
    try {
        this.getClass().getField(name).set(this,Boolean.TRUE);
    } catch (Throwable e) { }

}
```

This is not common way to do things, but sometimes it is necessary to do it this way.