# Naming the nodes of a Tree Structure

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I am implementing a tree based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17490124/3861689) answer. According to the given simple usage example, the new nodes are named after the position whey will have in the tree, so they are variables.
For example:

```
TreeNode<String> node0 = root.addChild("node0");
```

where **node0** is a new **TreeNode** and the **data** the new child will have.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631935/creating-a-variable-name-using-a-string-value) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974558/to-use-a-string-value-as-a-variable-name) I can not use a string for naming a variable.

I intend to have 26 children for each node my tree has. My question is simple, do I have to create the tree by creating by hand all the 26 possible nodes my tree will have, like below?

```
TreeNode<String> node0 = root.addChild("node0");
TreeNode<String> node1 = root.addChild("node1");
TreeNode<String> node2 = root.addChild("node2");
...
TreeNode<String> node25 = root.addChild("node25");
{
    TreeNode<String> node00 = node0.addChild("node00");
    ...
    {
        //the above code for all the nodes of the tree
    }
}
```

or am I missing a better solution? Thank you

Comment: why don't you add the 26 children in a loop? `for (int id = 0; id < 26; ++id) { root.addChild("node" + id); }`

Comment: @Turing85 this will work for root but what about the node0 for example? I cannot use node+"0" variable to do node0.addChild(...).

Comment: You can always nest another loop inside the loop. If you want to pass the depth of construction as a parameter, you can use recursion instead.

Comment: @Turing85 I think you are missing the point, I can use loops to add the nodes but I cannot name the parent node. Please take a look at the references I included. If I am missing the point, you may explain to me how node0 (parent name) from node0.addChild field will be constructed.

Comment: If you want the variable name (`nodeXY`) to be constructed dynamically from the `String` then the answer is: no, that is not possible. But why not use some sort of collection to manage your nodes (i.e. arrays or `List`s)?

Comment: Have you considered using a Map<String, TreeNode<String>> allowing the Map key to be the variable name you want to constuct.

Comment: @Turing85 this is the plan B, I was wondering if I could make it work based on the above Tree implementation.

Comment: @Ian Mc Interesting! I will give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would store the "name" of every node in a member variable and define a getter for it. I would also add a method to get the number of children the node already has. If you do that, you will name your nodes automatically when you instantiate them. In the class definition, add:

```
public class TreeNode<T> implements Iterable<TreeNode<T>> {

    T data;
    TreeNode<T> parent;
    List<TreeNode<T>> children;

    ...

    // A string containing the node name, (e.g. "210")
    String name;


    // A name getter method
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    // A method to get the number of children that the node has
    public int getNumChildren() {
        return this.children.size();
    }

}
```

Now, you can name the nodes automatically in the constructor:

```
public TreeNode<T>(T data, TreeNode<T> parent) {
    ...
    this.parent = parent;
    int numParentChildren = parent.getNumChildren();
    this.name = parent.getName() + numParentChildren;
}
```

Regarding your question about Tree creation, it would be better to encapsulate it in a method:

```
public LinkedList<TreeNode<T>> createTree() {
    //Root TreeNode
    TreeNode<T> root = new TreeNode<T>(data, null);

    //TreeNode on which we currently operate
    TreeNode<T> current;
    //List of treenodes holding the result
    List<TreeNode<T>> treeList = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
    //Queue holding the nodes for which we will create 26 children elements
    Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
    treeList.add(root);
    queue.add(root);

    for (int i=0; i< (some number); i++) {
    current = queue.remove();
    child = new TreeNode<T>>(data, current);
    current.addChild(child);
    queue.add(child);
    treelist.add(child);
    }
    return treeList;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

While a variable name may not take on a dynamic nature, a Map allows an abstraction to put/get a TreeNode based on a key which has a nomenclature you design (i.e. based on the level of the tree, and it's node position).
This allows the creation of your nodes in a loop.

You may want to consider a method like this for ease of use:

```
public String getKeyName(int treeLevel, int nodePosition) {
    // Build the key name...
}
```