# Execute an instructon in java in string format

Tags: java

I need to execute this instruction:

jButton1.setBackground(Color.orange);

but , jButton1 comes by a variable that i recover from a Data Base.

```
String b="jButton1";
```

and now I have to execute :

```
  ***b + ".setBackground(Color.orange)" ***
```

But Eval function is not aplicable.
How can I execute this String *** boton + ".setBackground(Color.orange)"***  as an instruction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

Comment: what is exactly "to execute" ? And what is the "Eval" function you mentioned here?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Also your design looks like a big code smell. Storing variable names in a database? Awful idea.

Comment: You are probably looking for what is called "Reflection" in java. (See similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38539512/11441011)) With this, you can get the field via the variable name on runtime.

Comment: Maybe GroovyShell will help?