# How to use Jenkins variable inside another variable

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
def var1 = "test"
def test = "Hello"
```

Now I want to print "Hello" using `var1` variable, like:

```
echo "${{var1}}"
```

But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea (I'm aware of) to make it work is the following piece of code:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
def var1 = "test"
@Field
def test = "Hello"

def field = this.getClass().getDeclaredField(var1)
field.setAccessible(true)
println field.get(this)
```

What you tried will not work for sure. @the_storyteller's idea with `Map` also makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, Groovy doesn't support referencing variables using a String variable name.

The best way I know to reference a value using a String is to store it in a map, and query the map. You can find an example in this answer: [To use a string value as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974558/to-use-a-string-value-as-a-variable-name)