# How to make a class immutable in java with date field in it?

Tags: java, immutability

I have created an immutable class with a date field. How do I ensure that even the date field is immutable, since even if you make date field final you can still assign a different value to it later?

Comment: [A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) - Oracle

Comment: In addition to the answers, which suggest or imply using a getter for the Date, ensure that your date field is private so that other classes cannot modify it.

Comment: If the user assigns a different value to the variable of the Date they got from, that doesn't change the Date value you have in your class

Comment: @MadProgrammer True, but the Date returned by the getter is not immutable. That's why copying it in the getter is important.

Comment: @McBrainy Yes, that part is true, but that's not what your question stated ;)

Comment: Besides, I could break it using reflection ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not my question. And you can even [break String using reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20945113/2093695).

Answer (score 18):

In your `getDate()` method, return a `new Date()` instance, instead of the same instance.

```
public Date getDate() {
    // Not correct.
    return this.date; // This will make your class mutable.

    // Instead use, 
    return new Date(this.date.getTime()); // This will make sure your date field cannot be changed.
}
```

Comment: In addition to that, we can do this also in constructor: `public Constructor(Date d){ this.date = new Date(d.getTime());}` so that if changes are made to `d` object are also not affecting date in original object.

Answer (score 7):

## *java.time*

Other Answers are correct that in showing strategies for fixing values within your objects.

Let me also recommend that you use the modern *java.time* classes rather than the terrible legacy classes. In place of `Date`, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). In place of `Calendar`, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

**The *java.time* classes are designed as immutable objects.** Methods such as `plus…`, `minus…`, `to…`, and `with` all produce a fresh object, leaving the original intact. The classes carry no *setter* methods.

Bonus tip: In your own immutable classes, you may find it useful to follow the method naming patterns established by the *java.time* classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a Bean(Class) with an immutable HAS-A Date Object.

```
 import java.util.Date;


public class MyBean {

    private Date date; // Immutable Date Step 1 Make Private

    public MyBean(Date date)
    {
         // Immutable Date Step 2 If Set through Constructor then get a specialised (sub class) Date.
        this.date= getImmutableDate(date);  // THIS METHOD RETURNS AN IMMUTABLE DATE
    }

    public MyBean(){} // Allow Default Constructor

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

     // Immutable Date Step 3- Allow setting of date only once!!
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        if(this.date==null)
        {
            this.date= getImmutableDate(date);  
        }
    }

    /* Override all Setter methods of Date class. So even if user gets reference of Date Object it is not the original date object
     * it would be a modified date object whose all setter methods do nothing*/
    private Date getImmutableDate(Date date)
    {
        /* This is an Anonymous Inner Class that extends java.util.Date class, it overrides all the setter methods
         * making the date object IMMUTABLE( i.e setXXX has no effect)
         * */
        date =new Date(date.getTime()){
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public void setYear(int year) {}

            @Override
            public void setMonth(int month) {}

            @Override
            public void setDate(int date) {}                

            @Override
            public void setHours(int hours) {}

            @Override
            public void setMinutes(int minutes) {}

            @Override
            public void setSeconds(int seconds) {}



@Override
        public void setTime(long time) {}

    };
    return date;
}
```

}

Comment: The Easiest way is using String. But if you want "java.util.Date" then above example will do

Comment: Failing silently in the setters like this seems like a bug waiting to happen... @Oliver the time in milliseconds would be better than a String, but the Date is best.

Comment: @McBrainy How do you think this code would fail? Please throw some more light on it.

Comment: @Oliver, someone using your API will get very confused if you have overridden all these methods. This may not be a good programming practice in many cases.

Comment: @Codebender Well this works. Using Joda API is a better alternative as I think, as DateTime object is immutable anyways. But if you don't want to use a whole API like Joda this could prove to be a good quick fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can clone date object so that it cannot be modified

```
public Date getDate (){
         return (Date) this.date.clone ();
}
```

Comment: All the instance returned by this method still mutable right.

Comment: this.date cannot be changed hence class will remain immutable although you can change cloned object

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple example of `immutable` class in `Java`

```
public final class Employee{  
    final String pancardNumber;  
    public Employee(String pancardNumber){  
        this.pancardNumber=pancardNumber;  
    }  
    public String getPancardNumber(){  
       return pancardNumber;  
    }
}
```

The above class is immutable because:

1. The instance variable of the class is final i.e. we cannot change
   the value of it after creating an object.
2. The class is final so we cannot create the subclass.
3. There is no setter methods i.e. we have
   no option to change the value of the instance variable.

These points makes this class as immutable. In case of `Date` attribute, you can use constructor to set your date with every new object and import `org.joda.time.DateTime` class. This is a better version than the `java.util.Date` because it is immutable. Using a java.util.Date would be dangerous as it is a mutable class and we can’t control the calling thread (which might modify it). Here is example.

```
public final class Bill {

    private final int amount;
    private final DateTime dateTime;

    public Bill(int amount, DateTime dateTime) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public DateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why, exactly, would we be worried about the "calling thread" modifying our private field? Through the getter? You can do as Codebender or Joni and effectively clone the Date when returning it from a getter.

Comment: @McBrainy: Good point. I agree with you. We can do it in that way.

Answer (score 1):

Identify the mutable instance variables(like date or hashmap) return new objects with copied content for all mutable objects. Immutable variables can be returned safely without extra effort.

See below example:

```
import java.util.Date;

public final class ImmutableClass
{

    /**
    * Integer class is immutable as it does not provide any setter to change its content
    * */
    private final Integer immutableField1;
    /**
    * String class is immutable as it also does not provide setter to change its content
    * */
    private final String immutableField2;
    /**
    * Date class is mutable as it provide setters to change various date/time parts
    * */
    private final Date mutableField;

    //Default private constructor will ensure no unplanned construction of class
    private ImmutableClass(Integer fld1, String fld2, Date date)
    {
        this.immutableField1 = fld1;
        this.immutableField2 = fld2;
        this.mutableField = new Date(date.getTime());
    }

    //Factory method to store object creation logic in single place
    public static ImmutableClass createNewInstance(Integer fld1, String fld2, Date date)
    {
        return new ImmutableClass(fld1, fld2, date);
    }

    //Provide no setter methods

    /**
    * Integer class is immutable so we can return the instance variable as it is
    * */
    public Integer getImmutableField1() {
        return immutableField1;
    }

    /**
    * String class is also immutable so we can return the instance variable as it is
    * */
    public String getImmutableField2() {
        return immutableField2;
    }

    /**
    * Date class is mutable so we need a little care here.
    * We should not return the reference of original instance variable.
    * Instead a new Date object, with content copied to it, should be returned.
    * */
    public Date getMutableField() {
        return new Date(mutableField.getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return immutableField1 +" - "+ immutableField2 +" - "+ mutableField;
    }
}
```

For more details :
http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/make-class-immutable-java/

Comment: Simple and Effective explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use defensive copying. This means that if you have to pass the date to some other class, for example through a method parameter or returned from a method, you should make a copy.

Making a copy of a Date is easy:

```
new Date(myDate.getting())
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way to do this.
Create a custom DateClass and Overrider the set** methods and dont provide any functionality to this methods.