# Accessing private variable of Model class without getters

Tags: java, model, private, getter-setter

I have a Model class defined in my project. and as usual it has some private variables and public getters and setters

```
public class Person{

 private ArrayList<String> mark;

 public void setMark(ArrayList<String> mark){
  this.mark = mark;
 }

 public void getMark(){
  return this.mark;
 }
}
```

Suppose in some other class I am using this Model like

```
Person person = new Person();
ArrayList<String> mark = new ArrayList();
mark.add("10");
mark.add("15");
mark.add("18");
person.setMark();
```

then the private variable of person holds the value "my name", the I am accessing the variable using public getter of the class like

```
ArrayList<String> localMark = person.getMark()
```

so as per my knowledge person.getMark() returns the reference of private variable name, so if I modify the local variable 'localMark', then it will effect the private variable of Person class, so there it breaks the private property of the variable

ex:

```
 ArrayList<String> localMark = person.getMark();
 System.out.println(localMark.get(0)); // will be "10"
 localMark.set(0,"25") // person.mark will be changed
 System.out.println(person.getMark().get(0)); //will be printing "25"
```

most of the developers following the same design pattern I guess, but what is the correct way to create `Models`

**EDIT**

As per the comment of vinod I checked, and Strings it passes value but not reference but for ArrayList... it returns reference.

Comment: *System.out.println(person.getName()); //will be printing "new Name"* ==> Did you check?. I think you should check what is printed :)

Comment: How do you modify the localName? What about Immutability?

Comment: I din't but if it returns the reference it should be the value isn't it ?

Comment: @Raf locaName is a local variable of another class, I can modify it with any value there

Comment: I down-voted your question because you posted something which won't happen to Strings. *re-assigning* the reference won't change a thing because java is *pass-by-value*. Next, the changes you do on the instance in a different class will affect the actual instance if you have *mutable* instances returned by your getter (which you shouldn't, you should return defensive copies of mutable instances)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I don't think, it requires a down vote. Adding an answer expalining what's wring will be the nice approach afaik :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - But he should try his code before posting. :). Don't you think my comment gives him enough info / hints? :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar That is what my point. You can guide him with an answer.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - Okie dokie :P

Comment: @Raf - Well, *Reflection* could be used to break *immutability*. But the OP is merely re-assigning references

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar interesting. I am yet to learn Reflections. Thanks.

Comment: @Raf - No problemo. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable) if you are interested :)

Comment: please reload the question, I have tried and checked,for strings there is no issues, it returns the value, not reference.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I think its the time to remove the down vote :)

Comment: @VividVervet - Done. Check my answer as to why the value is reflected in case `List` is used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the instance being exposed by call to `get()` is *mutable*, then whatever changes you make in some other place will be reflected in the instance everywhere it is used.

Example :

```
methodX classA - 
 List<String> locaNamesList = person.getNamesList();
 locaNamesList.clear();

Somewhere else
methodY classB -
List<String> locaNamesList = person.getNamesList(); // note the same person instance should be used.
//locaNamesList will be empty here
```

Just re-assigning the reference won' change anything.

```
List<String> locaNamesList = person.getNamesList();
locaNamesList = null; // won't change the actual list. You are setting local field locaNamesList to null and not the actual instance.
```

You have to use *defensive-copies* of mutable instances and pass them around if you don't want the original instance to be changed by external players (provided you can't make the instance itself *immutable*)

Comment: then how do I redesign my model class ? what you mean by defencive copies ?

Comment: @VividVervet - Defensive copy means - *creating a new Object which is exactly same as the original. This is usually done via a copy constructor . You can use a factory or other method*. Thus you will return a copy of your instance and not the actual instance itself

Answer (score 3):

You have a reference (name) to an object instance (the value of name). As the reference is private, you're in full control of it.

When you return a reference, you in fact **return** it **'by value'**, meaning that a **copy of the reference** is returned. Both references point to the same value (the String instance)).

An outside caller obtaining the reference can assign a new value, but your model's own reference is unaffected by that and still points to the value.

**It's like a dog (object) on a leash (reference).**

- When you return a reference you're returning a new leash onto the same dog.
- The owner of the new reference can modify your dog (pet it, shave it, whatever) when the dog is mutable (which Strings are not, so it cannot be modified)
- ...or he can attach a new dog to his leash
- ...but he can never (reflection aside) attach YOUR leach to another dog.

Comment: Liked the Dog and leash analogy. +1