# How can I remove " ' " from a String

Tags: java

I tried:

```
mystring.replace("'","");
```

and also

```
mystring.replaceAll("[']","");
```

But none of them work, please show me how to remove that `'` from my string.

Comment: You have space, so use `mystring.replace(" ' ","");`

Comment: Are you assigning the result of the call to `replace` or `replaceAll` to a new variable?  They don't change the `String` that you call them on.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you post input as well as output of your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a Java string really immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you assinging the result of this method? You should be calling it like this :

```
mystring = mystring.replace("'","");
```

> Strings in Java are immutable - when you call replace, it doesn't change the contents of the existing string - it returns a new string with the modifications. So you want:

This is why you have to assign the return value to a string.

As a note, this also applies to all methods in `String`. Methods like `toUpperCase()` return the new string. It does not change the existing.

Comment: wow, you are right, thank u ;) I will aceept ur answer after 10 mins ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, for better help faster please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Next, Java [`String` is *immutable*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553110/2970947), so you must update the `mystring` reference. Something like,

```
String mystring = "Papa John's";
mystring = mystring.replace("'","");
System.out.println(mystring);
```

Output is (as requested) without `'`

```
Papa Johns
```