# java - discrepancy when passing parameter of different type and update

Tags: java

in below code although I am updating StringBuilder roar3 inside roar(String roar1, StringBuilder roar3) method but how it affects roar2 in main() method? Same thing does not affect int x or y in intUpdate(int  x, int y) also not for String roar1.

```
public class TestReference {

    public void roar(String roar1, StringBuilder roar3) {
        roar1.concat("!!!");
        roar3.append("!!!");
    }

    public void intUpdate(int  x, int y) {
        x=1;
        y=2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String roar1 = "roar";
        StringBuilder roar2 = new StringBuilder("roar");
        new TestReference().roar(roar1, roar2);

        System.out.println(roar1 + " " + roar2);


        int x=-1,y=-2;
        new TestReference().intUpdate(x, y);

        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Must be new classes..

Comment: tldr: 1) modifying an *object* in one place modifies *that same object* everywhere (see the the API for what methods *mutate* an object); 2) [re-]assigning to local variables does not modify any object or argument..

Comment: I love how upvotes come so freely for certain kinds of questions :}

Comment: @user2864740 I don't think it is a dupe of that. Because, the confusion is really about the immutability.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I'd say "half duplicate" (due to bringing in the ints), there are definitely questions that are duplicates wrt *String being immutable*. Feel free to link them in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1 (re-assignment of a variable is not related to mutability of the object being assigned) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable (the mutable is defined at the contract level)