# Can we rely on Gson's ability to modify val attributes?

Tags: kotlin, gson, immutability

Kotlin's `val` attributes, by design are immutable. They are supposed to be fixed and unchangeable after initialization.

However, I accidentally found out that `Gson` is able to modify those attributes.

Consider this example:

```
//Entity class:
class User {
    val name: String = ""
    val age: Int = 0
}
```

Since the `name` and `age` are defined as `val` and are initialized to empty string and zero, they must remain the same and never change.

However, this test succeeds:

```
fun main() {
    val json = "{\"name\":\"Mousa\",\"age\":30}"
    val user = Gson().fromJson<User>(json, User::class.java)
    assert(user.name == "Mousa")
    assert(user.age == 30)
    print("Success")
}
```

Using this feature makes the code cleaner. Because those attributes are modified by Gson and cannot be modified by the rest of our code. Otherwise, I need to provide some mutable backing fields for Gson and some immutable attributes for the rest of the code.

I don't know if this is a "Feature" of `Gson` or a "Bug". So my question is: can we rely on this, or this behavior might change later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run `javap -p User.class`, you get the following output:

```
public final class q54491286.User {
    private final java.lang.String name;
    private final int age;
    public final java.lang.String getName();
    public final int getAge();
    public q54491286.User();
}
```

Kotlin immutability is backed by no mutator methods generated for fields that are (implicitly) declared `private` and `final`.
Unless you define a custom type adapter, Gson, by design, uses neither accessors nor mutators during serialization and deserialization respectively [by design](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/gson/da5cae371e8b739fe63a6c6d16debf7b297dea0e/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java) for plain data object classes (See more [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/GsonDesignDocument.md) in the *Using fields vs getters to indicate Json elements* section).
Also, Gson can modify `final` fields, and that's a design choice too.

Due to heavy use of reflection, immutability is pretty a *relative* thing in Java.
For example, I can easily modify an immutable (by design) string using reflection making it a sort of mutable (by [intention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable/20945113)):

```java
final String s = "foo";
final Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
valueField.setAccessible(true);
valueField.set(s, new char[]{ 'b', 'a', 'r' });
System.out.println(s);
```

This produces `bar` when using my `java` from `java version "1.8.0_191"`.
No immutability, he-he.

From the other hand, if your class could be detected by Gson type adapter strategies redefining method in a generic way (Gson prohibits re-defining `Object` and `JsonElement` type adapters), you'd be able to write a custom deserializer that prohibits Kotlin-generated classes (detected by the `kotlin.Metadata` annotation) from having read-only fields being deserialized (not sure if it has a benefit, though).
Or just implement a deserializer that will scan a JSON stream/tree for non-read-only fields and use them only while constructing a new `User` object with its legal constructor not using reflection.

> I don't know if this is a "Feature" of Gson or a "Bug".

Summarizing it up, it's a feature.

> So my question is: can we rely on this, or this behavior might change later?

This, most likely, will not ever change in Gson 2.x.
As far as I know, there are no any plans to release a major update, Gson 3.x and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for the nice and complete answer. And welcome to SO.